# How to get maximum number of processes for a user in windows in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a very trivial question but I couldn't get any answer in Google.

As far as I know there is a limit of maximum processes a user can create. How can I get this variable into C++?

I am using Visual C++ , Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks in adcance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472389/how-to-increase-the-maximum-number-of-child-processes-that-can-be-spawned-by-a-w seems relevant

Comment: Windows doesn't have baked-in limits like that.  As memory allows.  If you need to know then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: If [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) fails it reports an error by returning zero. This is all the information you will get, and frankly, I cannot possibly think of a scenario where this is not enough. I guess the question occured after you opted for the wrong solution, as hinted to by @Hans already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think there is any such uppper limit however that may depend on your virtual stack space.

You may also check [Pushing the Limits of Windows: Processes and Threads](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/07/08/3261309.aspx)

Comment: What is virtual stack space?