# DoModal main application returning -1 code randomly

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a vc++ program that calls another large exe written in MFC vc++ over and over with create process threads.
sometimes the exe fails to start because the DoModal in the exe fails, but not always. out of 6 calls, 2 may not start.

is there some sort of resource limit? or something else that can identify the problem rather than a -1 return code?
It seems to be mainly when I run as a service under localsystem account, not sure why - might be a red herring.

In the main application startup main window:-

```
 CTestDlg dlg;
 int ret = dlg.DoModal();
```

return code is sometimes -1.

Comment: Don't tag something as `random` just because it involves a bug which you can't reliably reproduce. `random` should be reserved for questions involving the use of random number generators. I am thus deleting that tag.

Comment: I don't think a service can open a window.

Comment: GetLastError checked?

Comment: yes, it was always 0.   the solution was the heap limit when running as a service is different to normal.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was in article: [How to increase the maximum number of child processes that can be spawned by a windows service -- desktop heap limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472389/how-to-increase-the-maximum-number-of-child-processes-that-can-be-spawned-by-a-w)

worked for me, but had to reboot after making changes for it to take effect.